# Unable to resolve module ./CardContainer error when running react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a react-native app and came across errors when running. I can't seem to figure it out after hours.
Anyone able to help? I'm learning react native and I can't seem to figure out why this is so. I've spent hours updating so many NPM packages I couldn't even count. Any hint or way to debut this? I'm so lost.

Files:
[image: Code Tree]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTZVR.png):

```
Unable to resolve module ./CardContainer from C:\Users\usama\hp4\node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\Stack\CardStack.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\Stack\CardContainer(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\Stack\CardContainer\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
   7 | import { MaybeScreenContainer, MaybeScreen, shouldUseActivityState } from '../Screens';
   8 | import { getDefaultHeaderHeight } from '../Header/HeaderSegment';
>  9 | import CardContainer from './CardContainer';
     |                            ^
  10 | import { DefaultTransition, ModalTransition } from '../../TransitionConfigs/TransitionPresets';
  11 | import { forNoAnimation as forNoAnimationHeader } from '../../TransitionConfigs/HeaderStyleInterpolators';
  12 | import { forNoAnimation as forNoAnimationCard } from '../../TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators';
```

Comment: You mean that `CardContainer.js.DELETE.e8b4...`?

Comment: Errors should be in code blocks. Not only is it hard/annoying to read when it's a screenshot, it also prevents other people from finding this on Google, it takes up precious data for mobile users, ...

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs Sorry, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a `CardContainer.js.DELETE.e8b4...` in the same directory as your `CardStack.js`, but no actual `CardContainer.js` *(or similar allowed extensions)*. It seems like you (accidentally?) renamed that file incorrectly.

Comment: Thing is, I never did such a thing, and it wont allow me to remove the "delete". I created a fresh project from expo and these are the files by default. Any way to get the default CardContainer.js from somewhere and somehow add it?

Comment: You could get it from [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/views/Stack/CardContainer.tsx) (although that's the source code), but if it's an actual dependency, you should attempt (upgrading and) reinstalling it. I.e. `rm -r node_modules; rm yarn.lock; yarn` or `rm -r node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm i`. Perhaps even clear your NPM/Yarn cache, although theoretically those should never get corrupted.